# How do I convert a 2D column vector to a 1D vector in python for a pearsonr calculation in python?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scipy

I am fairly new to working with python and am struggling a bit on this.

In this code I have defined xhand to be collected data of a hand moving horizontally and xpred to be a prediction of the hand movements based off of neural firing collected at the same time xhand was collected. So now I am trying to calculate the Pearson r value to determine if they are correlated or not.

these are the libraries i have installed:

```
import statistics as stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import scipy.stats
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

%matplotlib inline
```

To calculate the pearson r for my data this is what I tried:

```
correlation_coefficient, p_value = pearsonr(xhand, xpred)
```

now when I ran this I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-b9cb969c9e2c> in <cell line: 17>()
     15 
     16 # double check
---> 17 correlation_coefficient, p_value = pearsonr(xhand, xpred)
     18 print("Sum of squares correlation value:",r)
     19 print("Built in function correlation value:",correlation_coefficient)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (1000,1) and (1000,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 1000 (dim 0)
```

so then I figured that it needs to be flattened so I ran this:

```
correlation_coefficient, p_value = pearsonr(xhand.flatten(), xpred.flatten())
```

and subsequently got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-5eec4d420c4b> in <cell line: 17>()
     15 
     16 # double check
---> 17 correlation_coefficient, p_value = pearsonr(xhand.flatten(), xpred.flatten())
     18 print("Sum of squares correlation value:",r)
     19 print("Built in function correlation value:",correlation_coefficient)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py in pearsonr(x, y, alternative, method)
   4766 
   4767     if n < 2:
-> 4768         raise ValueError('x and y must have length at least 2.')
   4769 
   4770     x = np.asarray(x)

ValueError: x and y must have length at least 2.
```

I tried using xhand.reshape(-1) and xpred.reshape(-1) and .ravel() as well but I keep getting the same error.

How can I fix this, I don't know of any other ways convert them from 2D to 1D?

Comment: What's `xhand` and `xpred` `shape`?  `dtype`?  And confirm `xhand.flatten().shape`.  What's their source?  How about `type`?  `np.matrix` by any chance?

Comment: If it's `np.matrix`, `flatten()` converts a (n,1) to a (1,n) matrix.  `flatten` of a `ndarray` makes it (n,), but `np.matrix` has to be 2d, so it adds the new leading dimension.  The use of `np.matrix` is discouraged because of quirks like this in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying is correct if `xhand` and `xpred` are NumPy arrays.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(483465834568457)
xhand = rng.random(size=(1000, 1))
xpred = rng.random(size=(1000, 1))

stats.pearsonr(xhand, xpred)
# ValueError: shapes (1000,1) and (1000,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 1000 (dim 0)

stats.pearsonr(xhand.ravel(), xpred.ravel())
# PearsonRResult(statistic=-0.02435495881216112, pvalue=0.44170202221356253)

stats.pearsonr(xhand.reshape(-1), xpred.reshape(-1))
# PearsonRResult(statistic=-0.02435495881216112, pvalue=0.44170202221356253)

stats.pearsonr(xhand.flatten(), xpred.flatten())
# PearsonRResult(statistic=-0.02435495881216112, pvalue=0.44170202221356253)
```

As a comment mentions, if `xhand` and `xpred` are not arrays, this might not work. So consider explicitly converting them to arrays and verifying that the shape is correct before continuing.

```py
xhand = np.matrix(rng.random(size=(1000, 1)))
xpred = np.matrix(rng.random(size=(1000, 1)))
stats.pearsonr(xhand.reshape(-1), xpred.reshape(-1))
# ValueError: x and y must have length at least 2.

xhand = np.asarray(xhand).ravel()
xhand.shape # (1000,)
xpred = np.asarray(xpred).ravel()
xpred.shape # (1000,)
stats.pearsonr(xhand, xpred)
```

Comment: `xhand.A1` is a shortcut that does this conversion to array followed by ravel.  Probably added long ago by a dev who was frustrated by the default behavior of `matrix.flatten`.

Comment: Thanks! I got it figured out, I did have to convert it to an array, this is the code that worked for me: correlation_coefficient, p_value = pearsonr(np.array(xhand).flatten(), np.array(xpred).flatten())